# Unable to get readable encoded string

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I am trying to use google-kms nodejs library.

What I was expecting is that the end result will be encrypted text but what I get is a buffer if I don't decide base64 or if I do then I get something like `$�k+��l�k��:`

Does someone know what's wrong r is my expectation wrong about the encoded text.

```
exports.encryptKMS = async (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';

  const projectId = 'xxx';

  const kms = require('@google-cloud/kms');
  const client = new kms.KeyManagementServiceClient();

  const locationId = 'global';

  const keyRingId = 'Test-Ring-01';

  const cryptoKeyId = 'Test-Crypto-01';

  const cryptoKeyPath = client.cryptoKeyPath(
    projectId,
    locationId,
    keyRingId,
    cryptoKeyId
  );

const [result] = await client.encrypt({name: cryptoKeyPath, plaintext: message});

  console.log(result);

  const cryptoText = Buffer.from(result.ciphertext, 'base64').toString('utf-8');

  console.log(cryptoText);

  res.status(200).send(cryptoText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct to me, the encrypted object will be a base64 encoded binary string which you won't be able to see any structure in. If you take that result and feed it back into Decrypt you should recover the original message.

If you wanted a readable string, please provide more info -- there's such a thing as "[Format-Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption)" which attempts to encrypt data in such a fashion that it will continue to be in a compatible format to the input, for when systems aren't ready to handle encrypted data. Cloud KMS doesn't support format-preserving encryption, but I may have some suggestions depending on what you need.

Thanks for using GCP and Cloud KMS!

Comment: Thanks Tim... The problem is that I have 2 Cloud Functions. One encrypts and other decrypts. If I try to feed the $xxxxx to decryptor. It complaints about JSON being invalid. As of now I am just trying my hands on KMS but my intention is to encrypted the DB pwd and later decrypt in a cloud Function / Cloud Run app. M also looking into secrets in GCP env...

Comment: JSON cannot support binary data so you need to encode the result, usually using base64. Then, in your other function, decode the result (putting it back to binary) and then decrypt it.